# Rabbitmq ERROR CachingConnectionFactory:1302 - Channel shutdown: channel error;

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-cloud-stream

I am getting this error

ERROR CachingConnectionFactory:1302 - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-message-ttl' for queue 'xyz.xyz.dlq' in vhost 'qa40': received the value '10000' of type 'signedint' but current is none, class-id=50, method-id=10)

Where my config file has this

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.xyz.destination=xyz
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.xyz.group=xyz_group
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.xyz.consumer.max-attempts=1
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.xyz.consumer.republish-to-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.xyz.consumer.requeue-rejected=false
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.xyz.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.xyz.consumer.dlq-ttl=10000
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.xyz.consumer.dlq-dead-letter-exchange=
```

I am using delay exchange i.e

```
public class xyzDlqConsumer extends RerouteDLQMessages {

    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = xyz.xyz_group;
    private final static String DLQ = QUEUE_NAME + ".dlq";

    public String getOriginalQueue() {
        return QUEUE_NAME;
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = DLQ)
    private void callRepublish(Message failedMessage) {
        rePublish(failedMessage);
    }
}

public abstract class RerouteDLQMessages {

    private static final String X_RETRIES_HEADER = "x-retries";
    private static final String DELAY_EXCHANGE = "dlqReRouter";
    @Value("${RETRIES_COUNT}") . //3
    private Integer retriesCount;
    @Value("${DELAY_TIME}") //10000
    private Integer messageDelay;
    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;


    protected abstract String getOriginalQueue();

    public void rePublish(Message failedMessage) {

        Map<String, Object> headers = failedMessage.getMessageProperties().getHeaders();
        Integer retriesHeader = (Integer) headers.get(X_RETRIES_HEADER);
        if (retriesHeader == null) {
            retriesHeader = Integer.valueOf(0);
        }

        if (retriesHeader < retriesCount) {
            headers.put(X_RETRIES_HEADER, retriesHeader + 1);
            headers.put("x-delay", messageDelay * retriesHeader);
            this.rabbitTemplate.send(DELAY_EXCHANGE, getOriginalQueue(), failedMessage);
        } else {

            //do whatever you want after three attempts
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange delayExchange() {
        DirectExchange exchange = new DirectExchange(DELAY_EXCHANGE);
        exchange.setDelayed(true);
        return exchange;
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding bindOriginalToDelay() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(new Queue(getOriginalQueue())).to(delayExchange()).with(getOriginalQueue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all;

> inequivalent arg 'x-message-ttl' for queue 'xyz.xyz.dlq' in vhost 'qa40': received the value '10000' of type 'signedint' but current is none, class-id=50, method-id=10)

Queues are immutable; you can't change their properties after they are created.

You are trying to declare a queue with ttl set to 10000 whereas one already exists with that name with no ttl `current is none`.

You can't do that; you have to delete and re-create the queue if you want to add a ttl.